# wildfly18 Hot deploy existing deployed and new html, js files (static content) without restaring wildfly domain slave server

Tags: java, wildfly, production, hotdeploy, wildfly-18

We are using WildFly 18 domain server and On slave server, we want to change existing deployed js, html files content and also we want to add new js, html files without restarting the server.

So, Is there any way we can achieve this hot deployment of files for WildFly18 domain mode server?

Answer (score 0):

You could try exploded deployments or overlays, but you will need to redeploy after changing the content.